# Android, What is the right way to write a file to a subdirectory of the data/data/'package' folder

Tags: android, database, fileoutputstream, illegalargumentexception, path-separator

I have been trying for the last couple of days to find the right way of writing a file to a subdirectory of the android data folder.
Most answers i found were not clear or didn't address the problem in a right and working way so i finally decided to ask.
I am giving a user the possibility of backing up his data on my server by basically uploading the database to the server through a php script.
The database is located in

```
'/data/data/com.package/databases/data.db'
```

The problem here is when a user wants to reload a backed up database.
The application Downloads the file and should then write it (Overwriting the old one) to the /databases/data.db' file, and then reload.
I have managed to get everything to work up until where i have to write the downloaded file because FileOutputStream throws an illegal argument exception saying that i can't use path separators in the path.
I understand that FileOutputStream can only write to the first level of the data folder and not to subdirectories.
How can this be done?
If it can't be done, is there any way to set the default database path to the first level of the 'data' directory to solve this problem?
If this is a completely wrong approach to what i want to obtain i am open to critique but it would still be nice to get an answer, just for future knowing.

```
public void aSyncDatabaseDownloadFileFinish(PhpWrapper feed) {
    if (validateServerResponse(feed.Result)) {
        // Copy Database to Directory
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput(ctx.getDatabasePath(DataDatabaseHelper.DBNAME).getAbsolutePath(),
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(feed.DownloadedBytes, 0, feed.DownloadedBytes.length);
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.nofilesonserver), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be done?

In your case, [use `getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) to write a file into the standard location for databases for your app.

Regardless of your path separator issue, `openFileOutput()` will work with `files/` directory in your internal storage, not the `databases/` directory.

Comment: Yes! I have found and posted the solution.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I got the answer thanks to Squonk, Still can't believe that it was that simple.
For anybody having the same problem here is an example:

```
if (validateServerResponse(feed.Result)) {
        // Copy Database to Directory
        try {
             // This Solved the Exception
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ctx.getDatabasePath(DataDatabaseHelper.DBNAME), true);
            fos.write(feed.DownloadedBytes, 0, feed.DownloadedBytes.length);
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.nofilesonserver), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Thank you Squonk!